# Calculate mean across area in a 2D array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

**in a nutshell:** I need a fast(precompiled) function like *filter2d* from OpenCV with *double type* output. Not *integer*.

**Detail:**
I have numpy array which store the monochrome image from OpenCV.

I need to calculate the mean values of matrix for some square (for example) kernel like this:

```
kernel size = (3,3)
```

input array:

```
[[13 10 10 10]
 [12 10 10  8]
 [ 9  9  9  9]
 [ 9 10 10  9]]
```

output array:

```
[[ 10.22222222   9.44444444]
 [  9.77777778   9.33333333]]
```

For example: ***10.22222 = (13+10+10+12+10+10+9+9+9)/9***

I write this function:

```
def smooth_filt(src,area_x,area_y):
    y,x = src.shape
    x_lim = int(area_x/2)
    y_lim = int(area_y/2)
    result = np.zeros((y-2*y_lim,x-2*x_lim), dtype=np.float64)

    for x_i in range(x_lim,x-x_lim):
        for y_i in range(y_lim,y-y_lim):
            result[y_i-y_lim, x_i-x_lim] = np.mean(src[y_i-y_lim:y_i+area_y-y_lim,x_i-x_lim:x_i+area_x-x_lim])
    return result
```

But this is not fast enough.

Please tell me if there is a faster way to calculate this.

**Answer:**
I check all methods. You can see the code: http://pastebin.com/y5dEVbzX

And decide that blur is most powerful method it is almost independent on kernel size.

**The graph of one image processing with different methods. testing set is 298 images.**
[image]

Comment: You can use a convolution matrix with only coefficients equal to 1/9 and then sum the result to get the mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you interested in OpenCV solution: function which you need is [`cv2.blur`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur).
For most of cases it must works faster than convolution, since it has separate optimization for normalized kernels (sum of coefficient is equal to 1).

```
blurred = cv2.blur(img,(3,3))
```

See nice tutorial about smoothing [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html#gsc.tab=0).

Comment: Thank you. But cv2.blur return only int values.

Comment: @gelezko if you convert to image to float or double type, the output will also be float or double.

Comment: I decided that it is most powerful method. Thank you! I know about blur, but I did not know that it works with float.

Answer (score 5):

Calculating the average in blocks is simply convolving the image with 
a constant kernel.
You can use the `scipy.signal.convolve2d` for this:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9.
out = convolve2d(img, kernel, mode='valid')
```

The `mode='valid'` argument is required to only get the part of the result that you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you!. At the present moment it is the best answer. In the next day i decide it is the solution or not.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html). It's pretty straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as ss

data = np.array([[13, 10, 10, 10],
                 [12, 10, 10,  8],
                 [ 9,  9,  9,  9],
                 [ 9, 10, 10,  9]])
kernel = np.ones((3,3))
kernel /= kernel.size

ss.convolve2d(data, kernel, mode='valid')
```

this gives

```
array([[ 10.22222222,   9.44444444],
       [  9.77777778,   9.33333333]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit [integral function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#integral), that calculates the sum of values from (0,0) to (i,j) elements.

*Using these integral images, you can calculate sum, mean, and standard deviation over a specific up-right or rotated rectangular region of the image in a constant time*

If "kernel" size is constant M, multiply resulting integral matrix by `1/M^2` to simplify mean calculation.

To get sum in some window (x1,y1)-(x2,y2), just find

```
S((x1,y1)-(x2,y2)) = I(x1,y1) + I(x2,y2) - I(x1,y2) - I(x2,y1)
```

pseudocode:

```
integral(src, sum)
multvalue = 1/(kernelsize*kernelsize)
sum = sum * multvalue
for every (x = 0..n-kernelsize-1, y = 0..n-kernelsize-1)
   mean[x,y] =  sum[x,              y] 
              + sum[x + kernelsize, y + kernelsize] 
              - sum[x,              y + kernelsize] 
              - sum[x + kernelsize, y]
```

Comment: Interesting solution. If you can - please provide more detail( I talk about code)

Comment: I don't know Python enough - see straightforward pseudocode

Comment: Is suspect that time is so large (100x) due to slow matrix access methods here: `means[x,y] = src_integral[x,y] ...`. (Inbuilt functions like `blur` have direct access in C-code)