# How to sweep an squared area in a dataframe of pixels in python to find the highest values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I have a directory with hundreds of csv files that represent thermographic images (288x383), currently the code scans each image, takes the mean of the central square region (10 rows x 10 columns), and delivers the mean value in the dataset that correlates each csv file with the mean value found .

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as m
%matplotlib inline

files = glob.glob('*.csv')
result = []

for file in files: 
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header = None)
    # Central squared area to extract values
    area_temp_measured = data.iloc[134:154, 181:201]

    avg_rect_temp = area_temp_measured.to_numpy().sum() / 400

    # append to the list
    result.append((file, avg_rect_temp))

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['Full_name', 'Temperature'])

df.head()
```

Out:

```
                  Full_name  Temperature  
0   2021-09-13_13-42-16.csv     19.53025  
1   2021-09-13_13-42-22.csv     17.79425  
2   2021-09-13_13-42-29.csv     17.62500  
3   2021-09-13_13-42-35.csv     18.06100  
4   2021-09-13_13-42-47.csv     18.73850
```

However, I want to update the code so that it can completely scan each file, in a similar square area (11x11) but in each location, find the highest average value of that same area, and deliver the value to the dataset along with the central coordinate of that area.

Example:

**01 |  02 |**  03 |  01 |  07 |  08 |  09 |  04 |  02 |  08
**03 | 12 |** 22 |  00 | 14 |  01 |  04 |  06 | 17 |  00
04 | 11 |  09 |  03 | 22 | 23 | 11 |  01 |  09 | 18
12 | 19 |  01 |  02 | 19 |  02 |  05 |  09 |  00 |  03
31 |  02 | 13 | 17 |  02 |  07 | 14 | 29 |  04 |  01

...

01 **|  02 |  03 |**  01 |  07 |  08 |  09 |  04 |  02 |  08
03 **| 12 | 22 |**  00 | 14 |  01 |  04 |  06 | 17 |  00
04 | 11 |  09 |  03 | 22 | 23 | 11 |  01 |  09 | 18
12 | 19 |  01 |  02 | 19 |  02 |  05 |  09 |  00 |  03
31 |  02 | 13 | 17 |  02 |  07 | 14 | 29 |  04 |  01

...

01 |  02 |  03 |  01 |  07 |  08 |  09 |  04 |  02 |  08
03 | 12 | 22 |  00 | 14 |  01 |  04 |  06 | 17 |  00
04 | 11 |  09 |  03 | 22 | 23 | 11 |  01 |  09 | 18
12 | 19 |  01 |  02 | 19 |  02 |  05 |  09 **|  00 |  03**
31 |  02 | 13 | 17 |  02 |  07 | 14 | 29 **|  04 |  01**

```
                  Full_name  Temperature    Coord_row  Coord_col
0   2021-09-13_13-42-16.csv     22.52000          144        200  
1   2021-09-13_13-42-22.csv     12.27240          250        150  
2   2021-09-13_13-42-29.csv     17.04500          123        300
3   2021-09-13_13-42-35.csv     38.04000          100        012
4   2021-09-13_13-42-47.csv     49.08500          220        180
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a 2D convolution on your image data and find the maximum value in the resulting image.

Make your DataFrame a NumPy array:

```
img = df.values
```

Blur the image with a (11, 11) kernel:, as per [Calculate mean across area in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151182/calculate-mean-across-area-in-a-2d-array):

```
blurred = cv2.blur(img, (11, 11))
```

If you don't want to install OpenCV, look at the other solutions in the same question, but be aware that the SciPy 2D convolution is much slower.

Find the coordinates of the maximum, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/9483964/463796:

```
coord_row, coord_col = np.unravel_index(blurred.argmax(), blurred.shape)

temp = blurred[coord_row, coord_col]
```

Comment: Nice, a question though: the `coord_row, coord_col` are the coordinates in the `blurred` array, right? so if OP is looking for the coordinates in the original array, should they add +5 to both of them?

Comment: By default `cv2.blur` uses reflection at the border, so the resulting blurred image has the same size. Border reflection probably makes sense in this case, but you brought up a good point. OP should consider what border behavior is wanted, and possibly offset the coordinates if only valid/full areas are considered.

Comment: interesting, I tried something with `convolve2d` and notice that the shape of the output was reduced by half the square area, but not with `cv2.blur` thanks

Comment: convolved2d can be called with `mode='same', boundary='symm'` to achieve the same behavior as calling `cv2.blur` with `borderType=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT`. The default behavior of `cv2.blur` with BORDER_REFLECT101 is ever so slighty different (see https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5), and has no counterpart in convolve2d, it seems. But all these methods create an image of the same output size.